# Questioning the validity of a proof of Dirichlet's test on improper integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a question about the validity of a proof of Dirichlet's test on improper integrals:

- $\,f$ and $g$ are continuous functions from $[a,+\infty]$ to $\mathbb{R}$,
- $\,\exists\,M\gt0$ such that $\vert\int_{a}^{t}f(x)\,dx\vert\,\le\,M,\forall\,t\ge\,a$
- $\,$g is decreasing and $\lim_{x\to\infty}{g(x)}=0$

Consider the following proof:
Let ε be a positive real number.

From the limit of dot 3 we have that $\vert g(x)\vert \lt \frac{ε}{2M}$ , for x > K, K $\in \mathbb{R}$

Now, $\vert\int_{t1}^{t2}f(x)g(x)\,dx\vert\ = \vert g(c)\vert\vert\int_{t1}^{t2}f(x)\,dx\vert,\,c\in\,[t1,t2]$, from the mean value theorem for integrals. 
 Picking $K \lt t1\le c \le t2$, it follows that:
$\vert g(c)\vert\vert\int_{t1}^{t2}f(x)\,dx\vert \lt \frac{ε}{2M}\vert\int_{a}^{t2}f(x)\,dx-\int_{a}^{t1}f(x)\,dx\vert\le \frac{ε}{2M}2M=ε$, so from Cauchy's test,
$\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x)g(x)\,dx $  converges.
I found that proof in a calculus textbook and I am not able to find how the deacreasing part of g is exploited. 
In addition, f has to be not negative in order to use this kind of mean value theorem 
(according to the same textbook), while the theroem is used here without taking that fact into account.
Am I missing something?
 I have this question because this is the main textbook of my studying, and as a result, I am confused.

Comment: maybe in the mean value theorem, monotone properties are needed

Comment: I think that's not the case, since this fact holds for constant functions, either f or g, as well.

Comment: It may hold for other functions, yes. But the general proof may (or may not) require a monotonic function

Comment: Well, I see that the general proof doesn't make such assumption. I see that this assumption is made for the 2nd MVT, but not for this one.